# Xcode scrolls text while typing

Tags: xcode, editor

Xcode seems to be doing something annoying today.

I like editing my source code so that I'm typing roughly in the vertical center of my Xcode window. I don't like typing near the bottom or the top of the window as it hides code right before or right after the code I'm busy editing.

Lately, while editing an implementation file, Xcode has a habit of scrolling the text so that I'm editing close to the bottom of the window. This scrolling is triggered every time any code completion takes place.

Has anyone seen this before? If so, how can I turn it off or is it simply a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be encountering a bug where one text view scrolls unexpectedly when a second window is open on the same file.  Make sure that the file is not open in any other windows if this is what's happening.

Comment: 'Bug' still exists in XCode 5 years later.  Rubbish.

Comment: Still there in xcode 8. Try deleting derived data. No point posting details as Apple just change this (like everything else) when the mood takes them. Do a search on SO for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed this in Xcode 5 and earlier. It appears that Apple has fixed this in Xcode 6. I am running Xcode 6.4 and no longer see the issue.