# Xcode [8] Editor scrolls on its own?

Tags: xcode, xcode8

## Environment

- Xcode 8
- MacOS 10.11.6
- MacBook Air (circa 2013)

## Problem

  I've noticed recently that the Editor in Xcode seems to periodically scroll-up on its own. Which I, at least, find very annoying.
  I've looked at a couple of other postings:
  - [Xcode scrolls text while typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910026/xcode-scrolls-text-while-typing)
  - [XCode auto-scroll when pressing Command after a text selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048284/xcode-auto-scroll-when-pressing-command-after-a-text-selection)
  But neither of them seem to provide a solution for me, as I'm not pressing the
  <kbd>Command</kbd>
  key and I'm not using multiple fingers on the touch-pad.
  It seems to happen most frequently when I'm working on code near the bottom of the file, I haven't been able to narrow down the cause-and-effect scenario more than that just yet.

## Query

- Has anyone else noticed this?
- Has anyone figured out a way to stop it?
- Is there a reasonable way to report this to Apple? There doesn't seem to be an Xcode section on the http://www.apple.com/feedback/ site.

Comment: http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Apparently someone already filed this with bug report.apple.com - as my attempt to do so was closed as being a duplicate.  No other information was provided (like ETA for fix) - but as this is "known" I will assume that it will eventually get fixed

Comment: Well, I wouldn't assume _that_ — I've got a dozen unfixed "duplicates". But filing the duplicate was still an important thing to do; thanks for doing that, and thanks for reporting back!

Comment: it happens every time for me, always scrolls up. When i am editing , I have a habit of using Command + S after a few lines to save and as soon as I make changes and  save, it scrolls up atleast 400 lines each time. Everytime!
I'm using XCode 8.1, mac OS 10.12.1

Comment: Same problem here (mac OS 10.11.6, Xcode 8.1). I also see it most often when working near the bottom of a file. Very frustrating!

Comment: Just to add, same problem here on XCODE 8.2.1, with the twist that its happening on my macbook pro (late 2015 model) whereas it does NOT happen on my Imac (mid 2013) with same version of XCODE ie latest one. Really annoying

Comment: Happens to me quite often as well.  Xcode 8.2.1, and I cannot upgrade to 9.0.1 yet - not until the whole team is ready to upgrade in lockstep.  iMac (2015 Retina) and MacBook Pro (2016 Retina Touchbar).

Comment: I was doing playgrounds for my swift course and I went to the next page and it was fine. It was scrolling up just a bit every time I pressed a character and hit space.

Answer (score 2):

Try to disable your XCode theme if you have one. We ended up with that bug by doing this trick!

Answer (score 0):

For XCode 10.1 changing the font size to 12 for the selected theme did the trick.